# How to get the base url where magento is installed?

Tags: php, magento, base-url

I need the base url of installation because I have to send as a parameter to an intermediary payment, and when it has subdomain just changing the base url or sub store with subdomain setting the url to index.php go wrong adding path

So I need something like this below select only in object already in the madroes Mage Magento

```
<?php
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
    $query = "SELECT value FROM  core_config_data WHERE scope = 'default' and path = 'web/unsecure/base_url'";  
    $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

    print_r($results);

?>
```

Return

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => http://url of install/ ) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$storeId = 0; // default, scope = default return base instalation
echo Mage::getStoreConfig('web/unsecure/base_url', $storeId);
```

Comment: Store id = 0 is the default installation without sublojas, languages ​​or websites

Answer (score -1):

You need [`Mage::getUrl`](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/geturl_function_parameters) and instead of just getting the base domain it can be used to get the finished URL in one go.

```
Mage::getUrl('path/to/notification', array('_store' => 'admin'));
```

Comment: Would not take the default shop because it can also be on a subdomain and the installation does not @clockworkgeek

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseUrl(); ?>
```